# Firebase Cloud Messaging not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I am using laravel 5.6 and trying to send notifications via Firebase but it does not work. Below is the script that is returning the error:

```php
$access_token = '******';
$reg_id = '*****';
$title = "New Notify";
$body = "Hello I am from Your php server";
$notification = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => '1'
);
$arrayToSend = array(
    'to' => $reg_id,
    'notification' => $notification,
    'priority' => 'high'
);
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);

$client = new GuzzleClient([
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'key=' . $access_token,
    ]
]);
$response = $client->post(
    'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    ['json' => $json]
);
```

Can someone kindly explain where I am wrong so that I can fix the issue.

Comment: you can pass the data directly in array form in `"json"` key so the value should be `["json"=>$arrayToSend]` and it will automatically convert it into json and add the `content-type` as `application/json`

Comment: What is the error you're getting?